# Backtracking in Java debug

Tags: java, debugging, backtrace

I have been searching for an answer to if it's possible to backtrack when doing Java debugging. For instance if I have the code:

```
int x = 1
int y = 0

//Exception will happen here
int z = x/y
```

And if I'm hitting the exception, I would like to go back.
And not just like dropping the frame, but also revert actual changes made to the Heap.
Is that currently possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is tool called [Chronon Time Travelling Debugger](http://www.chrononsystems.com/products/chronon-time-travelling-debugger)

It claims...

> Overview
>
> The Chronon Time Travelling Debugger allows you to playback Chronon
>   recordings and easily find root cause of defects.  It is specifically
>   built from the ground up to allow debugging of long running programs
>   that run for days/months and are highly multithreaded.
>
> The debugger plugs seamlessly into Eclipse adapting itself naturally
>   to your workflow. You can also use the Eclipse integration of the
>   Chronon Debugger to easily record programs on your development
>   machines from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible unless you implement some kind of undo stack, which, depending on what you do, could be extreme over-engineering. If you make your heap objects unmutable, and only change pointers visible to the caller once everything has completed without throwing an exception, then you'd get a relatively good approximation of the behavior you want, but it'll be hard to make ti thread-safe without using excessive synchronization, and could generate tons of boilerplate code that doesn't add a lot of value to the processes...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Omniscient debugger](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/)?

Comment: Yes I have looked into that. Even though that it looks very nice, I can only look at an already run execution, I would like to be able to actually change values after having stepped backed, and the get the program to run in a new direction.

Comment: @StefanE like you would if you changed the code to do this? I would just fix the code so it worked this way.

Comment: @StefanE could you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686946/how-to-use-omniscient-debugger